# Convert meters to radians

Tags: postgis

I'm doing a project in PostGIS where I need to know what is the conversion of meters to radians. I would like to know how to do or what to look for to carry out the doubt.

Comment: Anything here help? https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-meters-to-radians

Comment: This the same issue as converting meters to degrees (or reverse). There have been a lot of questions about it. You might want to do a search here. Here's a [similar question for the other direction](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270799/how-to-convert-resolution-in-degrees-to-resolution-in-meters) and [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75528/understanding-terms-in-length-of-degree-formula/75535#75535)